# express res.render option results in empty object

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server, express, javascript-objects

After receiving a RowDataPacket from MySql I pass into my options of res.render, however after I log the result in the client window I only receive a (what I think is) an empty object.
My server code:

```js
const data = await GetUserData(req.user.email)
res.render('index.ejs', {email: req.user.email, id: req.user.id, data: data})
```

My row data packet:

```js
[
  RowDataPacket {
    data: '[{"type": "c#", "script": "csharp script"}, {"type": "javascript", "script": "javascript script"}, {"type": "html", "script": "html script"}]'
  }
]
```

I'm quite confused as to why it doesn't log the rowDataPacket itself, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should post the more broader code because it looks like your `GetUserData` is becoming victim of asynchronous flow.

Comment: Did the row data packet you posted here, the one you are supposed to recieve from MySQL **OR** the one that comes after console.log and you were not supposed to recieve it?